# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_picture'

Tags: python, attributeerror, python-docx

I need to insert a picture(png format and named as {number2}.png) in the word(named as {number2}.docx), but it doesn't work and shows this error, someone can help me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIf3T.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. doc2 is a simple string. There is no way to add a picture to it. I suppose you should open the file, understand its format, before trying adding something to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your line:

```
doc2 = f'{number2}.docx'
```

you are assigning the value `'{number2}.docx'` to `doc2`. `'{number2}.docx'` is a string - for example if `number2 = "hello"` then `doc2 = "hello.docx"`.

I'm not sure about the add_picture part, but I'm assuming you may want something like:

```
doc2 = open(f'{number2}.docx')
```

or

```
with open(f'{number2}.docx'):

    # code
```

I am not sure if this works, or if you are using another module for the adding picture?
(I don't have enough reputation to comment)

Comment: I have multiple word documents and pictures to operate it. Like inserting 1.jpg to 1.docx, and 2.jpg to 2.docx So, I want to code it to repeat this operation. In this way, the picture name will change according to the name of the document.

Comment: I got it after change the codding of open docx part! thx